# Results out of order in part of my t-sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a dataset with two columns, TransDateString and TransDate. TransdateString is simply a nvarchar version of Transdate, so the data looks like this:

```
TransDate | TransDateString
2011-1-4  | 1-2011
2004-6-5  | 6-2004
2010-10-14| 10-2010
2012-7-21 | 7-2012
2010-10-11| 10-2010
2012-7-5  | 7-2012
```

What I'm trying to do is get the TransDateString into a variable in order by TransDate:

```
 SET @cols = STUFF((

        SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(A.TransDateString) FROM
        (
            Select c.TransDateString,
               Row_Number() Over (Partition By c.TransDateString Order By c.TransDate asc) RowNum
                FROM #dataSet c
        ) A
        Where RowNum = 1



        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

This works, but they are not in order. At runtime, I get something like `@cols=[[1-2011],[10-2010],[6-2004],[7-2012]]`

Comment: SQL Server 2106 has a [STRING_AGG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) method. Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. Time to upgrade. BTW [2016 SP1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1) brings in-memory tables, compression, columnstore indexes, partitions even to the Express Edition and LocalDb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with your input data, the code below gives you:

`[6-2004],[10-2010],[1-2011],[7-2012]`

```
  DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
 (
    [TransDate] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[TransDateString] VARCHAR(12)
 );

 INSERT INTO @DataSource ([TransDate], [TransDateString])
 VALUES ('2011-1-4', '1-2011')
       ,('2004-6-5', '6-2004')
       ,('2010-10-14', '10-2010')
       ,('2010-10-14', '10-2010')
       ,('2012-7-21', '7-2012')
       ,('2012-7-21', '7-2012');


SELECT 
STUFF((

        SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(A.TransDateString) FROM
        (
            Select c.TransDateString
               ,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY C.TransDateString Order By c.TransDate asc) RowNum
               ,Row_Number() Over (Order By c.TransDate asc) RowId
                FROM @DataSource c
        ) A
        WHERE RowNUm = 1
        ORDER BY RowId



        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2016 brings the [STRING_AGG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) function that can be used just like other aggregate functions:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(TransDateString,',')
FROM #dataSet c
ORDER BY TransDate
```

SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer supported. It's worth noting that [SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1) offers features that used to be part of the Enterprise SKUs, even to Express and LocalDB: compression, partitioning, in-memory tables, snapshots, masking, auditing etc.

The performance *and* licensing benefits make upgrading a very interesting idea.